# Adding a class to an html link in reStructured Text

Tags: restructuredtext

I try to add a class to a specific link adress

I wanna have this result in html language :

```
<a class="g-profile" href="http://plus.google.com/107666944254113159692" target="_blank">Winael</a>
```

So I try to do that :

```
.. role:: g-profile
   :class: g-profile

:Traduction: :g-profile:`Winael`_

.. _Winael: https://plus.google.com/107666944254113159692
```

But it still doesn't work. I don't know what to try.

Can someone help me ?

Thx in advance folks !

Best Regards,
Winael